# Geolocation necessary to get mayorship?

Tags: api, geolocation, foursquare

It's well known foursquare users are not able to get the mayorship of a venue if checkin comes via mobile website. But is it also necessary to send the geolocation of a user via foursquare API to get mayorship? If yes, how accurate must the geo information be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only check-ins that pass the user's actual lat/lng will be eligible for mayorship. The accuracy required depends on the venue, but the lat/lng reported must come from an independent source (i.e. the phone's GPS) and not be derived or set by the user.